# Is there a way to drop a table in the explorer of objectDB?

Tags: java, database, object-oriented-database, objectdb

Is there a way to drop a table in the explorer of objectDB (or is there a way to drop a table at all)?

I know that I can execute a 'delete from' query, but the table is still there and it's annoying to me because I created a lot of test entities and those tables are just hanging around without much use.

Comment: If you drop the table, Entity class remains know ? why do you need it ?

Comment: I want to restart the ID

Comment: have a table generator and update it when delete entities.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this forum thread](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/371) on ObjectDB website.

Regarding restarting ID, setting a new generator, as suggested by vels4j, should work.